# error importing module and loading files

Tags: python, import

I have a package structure like:

my_pkg:

- proj1

  - __init__.py
  - someModule.py
- proj2

  - __init__.py
  - foo.py
  - bar.json

Inside the *foo.py* module I have something like:

```
import json
def loadFromJSON(fileName):
    with open(fileName,'r') as f:
         xs = json.load(f)
    return xs

bar  = loadFromJSON('bar.json')
```

The problem is when I try to import things from **my_pkg**:

```
python
>>> from my_pkg import *
>>> ..../my_pkg/proj2/foo.py in loadFromJSON(fileName)
>>> --->  with open(fileName,'r') as f:
>>>           xs = json.load(f)
>>>       return xs
>>> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bar.json'
```

but if I do:

```
>>> cwd
>>> '.../my_pkg/proj2/`
>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar
```

It works. Could someone please explain me what's going on here?

Comment: I think you should use the full path of your "bar.json" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For completeness I transfer the comment to an answer)

I think you should use the full path for you "bar.json" file.

Answer (score 0):

just like you said, the point is 'cwd':
you can add your 'cwd' and then import module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('your cwd here')
```

then do:

```
from foo import bar
```